# How to run a function until a requirement/value is met, then return that value to the function that called it?

Tags: python

##### My code

```py
def new(url):
  html = (HTML hidden)
  ext = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=5))
  try:
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "templates/"+ext)
    os.mkdir(path)
  except FileExistsError:  
    new(url)
  else:
    with open(f"{path}/index.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(html)
    return ext  
      
      
@app.route('/create-api')  
def create_api():
  if "(URL hidden)/create" == request.environ['HTTP_REFERER']:
    args = request.args
    try:
      url = args.get('url')
    except:
      return redirect(url_for('home', error_msg="No URL provided."))
    else:
      r = requests.get(url)
      if r.status_code != 200:
        return redirect(url_for('home', error_msg="Not a valid URL."))
      else:
        ext = new(url)
        return redirect(url_for('home', url=f"(URL hidden)/{ext}"))
  else:
    print("NOPE")
    return 401
```

This code won't work because the function is being called inside the same function, causing it to not return anything to `create_api()`.

What I want is to continue trying to make directories, until one is available, then return to the `create_api()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recursively `return` the function to itself so the returned value of the function is actually used:

```
  except FileExistsError:  
    return new(url)
```

Depending on how many times this function will run, and how many unique directory names you will generate, you may want to include a new optional argument for `max_tries=0` or something to prevent a stack overflow.

Comment: Wouldn't this return the function object? and btw, the directories are random alphanumeric strings, so this isn't likely that a stack overflow would happen, but just in case ;)